# Where can I find the saved games or PGN files in the Play Magnus app?

Tags: computer-chess

I have completed games on the Play Magnus app and clicked on the option "Export game as PGN file " but I don't know where to find those saved games.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortuately, the Play Magnus app is not capable of creating PGN files. So, when you click on "Export game as PGN file", the game is copied to clipboard. You can then paste the game in a text editor and save it as a PGN file.